# How to define a route to match 3 parameters, when I'm only interested in the third?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

I'm trying to specify a route configuration that will allow a url similar to:

```
/{any sequence of characters}/{any sequence of characters}/{mexid}
```

We're currently redesigning an old system that used URLs of the previous format. Our new system has to catch these requests and redirect them to a new URL, but only if there are 3 URL parameters. It's only the third parameter that I'm interested in.

This is the route mapping that I'm using:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    null,
    "{param1}/{param2}/{mexid}",
    new { controller = "ShareClass", action = "FundFactsheet", mexid = "" }
);
```

the problem I'm having is that this is acting as a kind of catch-all for any invalid requests that come in, where I am only interested in this being the route for URLs with a mexid in them.

how can I define a route that will only apply to URLs that contain 3 parameters, only if the URL doesn't already match another route that I've more specifically defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to add route constraint (I haven't tested it yet but I think it should answer your question)

```
routes.MapRoute(
    null,
    "{param1}/{param2}/{mexid}",
    new { controller = "ShareClass", action = "FundFactsheet" },
    new { param1 = @".+", param2 = @".+", mexid = @".+" }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you remove the default for mexid?

The way you have the route right now, if you don't specify mexid then it will use "" as a default.

If you don't have anything unique about param1 and param2 then it will probably always take precedence over the default route, though.